# can not restore database from backup file because they are not the same database

Tags: sql-server

any one can help ?
I have Microsoft SQL SERVER Database **backup** , but when I am trying to restore the data from it , I got this message **"can not restore database from backup file because they are not the same database"**

**Note :**
this database was giving me error message **"the log scan number passed to database doesn't match the log  scan number in the log file "**

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information. Are you trying to restore a log file rather than an entire DB?

Comment: i am trying to restore the **entire DB**. Not Files. but i am sure they are the same DB

Comment: If you are restoring from a full database backup then it doesn't matter what is already there. You need to restore database, not restore files.

Comment: i know , that's what i am saying, i am trying to restore DB from a full backup file and i got this error message **"can not restore database from backup file because they are not the same database"**

Comment: How are you doing the restore?

Comment: 1- Right Click On DB > Tasks
2- Restore
3- Database
4- then i select from **Device**
5- and find my **.bak** file

Comment: @fawzymokhtar, on the Options page, select `Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)`.

Comment: thanks @DanGuzman that's worked fine for me , thanks again

Comment: @DanGuzman, please add the your answer as answer so people can find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The default SQL Server restore behavior includes the safety checks below as detailed in the [Restore topic in the SQL Server Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

- Restoring over an existing database with a backup taken of another database
- Restoring over a database using the full or bulk-logged recovery model where a tail-log backup has not been taken and the STOPAT option is not used
- Overwriting existing files

To override these checks, specify the `WITH REPLACE` option of the T-SQL `RESTORE` command or by selecting the `Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)` option in the Options page of the SSMS restore dialog.